# React - How to append an object as a field to FormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React, and am trying to send data back to my backend (DRF) using FormData to properly store the data. However, I am facing some issues with appending objects as fields into FormData, as it would be converted to [object, Object]. Is there any way to overcome this?

Here is my code for reference

my data before it is passed into formdata

```
{ quotation: "22222.00",
  customer: {customer_name: 'Customer A', address: 'Address B', number: '123456789'} 
}
```

how i pass the data into formdata

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('quotation', data.quotation);
formData.append('customer', data.customer);
```

after appending the data into formdata, when logging the formdata, this is what the customer field becomes

```
customer: [object Object]
```

this is the data received by the backend

```
{'quotation': '22222.00', 'customer': '[object Object]' }
```

Do guide me along, thanks all!

Comment: You can stringify the object before appending to the formData. Like - `formData.append('customer', JSON.stringify(data.customer))`

Comment: What happens if you use JSON.stringify on data.customer instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify(data.customer)` before appending to FormData.

Comment: thank you, it worked! Is it because my object was in JSON data format, hence I needed to change it to a string before formData could read it?